# Release apk won't run

Tags: android, flutter

I'm building release APK with `flutter run --release` but I'm getting this exception

```
Failed to register native method io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView.nativeRunBundleAndSource(JLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V in /data/app/com.example.myapp-1/base.apk
```

However, debug variant runs normally so if I run the app just with `flutter run` everything is fine.

By the way, I'm executing `flutter clean` before avery build.

What is the cause of this?

Comment: Try running `flutter clean` before you run the release version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Found the solution on my own, but I'm posting this answer for people who are having the same problem.*

Turns out that build.gradle was causing exception

```
shrinkResources true // for this to work minifyEnabled must be set to true
minifyEnabled true // if set to true apk will not build
```

Solved it by using only proGuard so snippet below is working `buildTypes` section of app-level build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    debuggable false
    useProguard true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
  }
}
```